# Handle republished work in apacite

Tags: bibtex, citing

How would I handle republished work with the `apacite` package for in-text citations? As according the blue book for apa, I need to have the publication date of the original and the republication. However I am not sure how to do that with bibtex, as every time I modify the year field it messes up the references section.

Proper citation looks like (Stevenson, 1886/2004). However mine lacks the 1886 part in it.

I have tried several ways of modifying the way I wrote the date field, but I could not figure it out. I am using the regular `\cite` command.

```
@book{JekyllHyde,
    title={{D}r. {J}ekyll and {M}r. {H}yde},
    author={Robert Louis Stevenson},
    publisher={Bantam Dell},
    address={New York, New York},
    year="2004",
    isbn={0-553-21277-X},
    note="Original work published in 1886"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not hard to do when you use the `originalyear` argument which creates the proper intext citation and will automatically add the note

```latex
@book{JekyllHyde,
    title={{D}r. {J}ekyll and {M}r. {H}yde},
    author={Robert Louis Stevenson},
    publisher={Bantam Dell},
    address={New York, New York},
    year="2004",
    isbn={0-553-21277-X},
    originalyear="1886"
}
```